# Persistence storage of ehcache in disk in Java

Tags: java, ehcache

I am working on caching for an web application.I need to write cache in disk for persistence storage.
How to do that.Please guide me.
After server restart cache should read for disk through Java.How to achieve this

Comment: A cache is normally used to hold data in memory, which would otherwise have to be retrieved from a persistent storage. Doesn't it defeat the point of a cache to persist it?

Comment: scenario can be in my application . for the first time it access 100 data file ... So it fetched from the Database. User performing some action .few files which is frequently used and few files which never accessed normally. So if i store frequent files in persistence storage.So performance will be more better

Comment: There is actually a page in the documentation of ehcache, which covers this topic: http://ehcache.org/documentation/configuration/fast-restart

Comment: I think persistence storage in disk option only available in license feature.I just want to implement open source and want to implement storage using by myself. any pointer will be helpfull.how to do that.i dnt want BigMemory Go and MAX featurs.

Comment: Periodically, in a background thread, you can loop through your cache and write it to a file. When you start the application, you can read from this file and set the cache.

Comment: @user1213178, how did you fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am using ehcache version 2.4.3 jar and I have implemented what you need using a trick. Worked for me.

Step 1:

```
 <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />
 <cache name="listOfStates" maxElementsInMemory="0" eternal="true" overflowToDisk="true"  diskPersistent="true"></cache>
```

Built and published the app. Above configuration created listOfStates.data file in my temp drive. (File has size too).

Step 2:

Changed `maxElementsInMemory="0"`to `maxElementsInMemory="1"` and built & published app. This time cached data is loaded from disk. Code( Spring method level cache I used using @Cacheable.) is not executed to cache the data.